# Load css with javascript without jankiness of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

In the pages of my site I'm using a series of animations with jquery (velocity to be precise), and everything works fine.

But there is a problem:

I wish that when some visitor does not have javascript enabled on his browser, then the site not automatically loads the css (which I modify it for use with javascript) and the site have not animated graphics.

To load the css with javascript I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     var cssLink = $("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/wp-content/themes/one/css/home.css'>");
     $("head").append(cssLink);
});
 </script>
```

But now there is a further problem:

- As soon as I open the site, for a split second, you see the first page and then it starts with the css is loaded via the javascript, then you see everything as I set in the second css (loaded with javascript).

How can I eliminate this false view before the loading of css with javascript?

Comment: An option would be to display:none the body or a wrapper and then show on document ready once you've injected your CSS file?

Comment: you could load jQuery from head and next to it call your script to load CSS without using document ready handler which in your case is useless. Or you could still from HEAD section include CSS link using only javascript, using jQuery is quite unrelevant in this case anyway

Comment: set body opacity to 0. then set  
 $(window).load(function(){
  $('body').css('opacity','1');
})

Comment: @Nishitmaheta But so for users with javascript disabled, BODY will still remain with opacity equals to 0

Comment: @A.Wolff if javascript is disabled then css also not append in head tag . as css file load using javascript

Comment: @Nishitmaheta Ok i misunderstood your comment then